# Why Paypal deprecated IPN feature in REST API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

As far as I know, Paypal REST API has no IPN feature provided. Even user setup notification URL in their account setting.

Paypal introduce Webhooks instead. But it requires HTTPS url.

What if some websites did not use SSL? Can they still trace a transaction's notification in REST API?

Comment: IPN at the profile level would send for many things; however, using HTTPS to protect customer information would be considered the best practice, and its enforced with the Webhooks.  You could consider pulling the information maybe using https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-payment-resources

Comment: IPN would send for many things? I don't understand if it has some secure concerns why Paypal allow user define notification url without HTTPS?